# How to find memory buffer size limits in SONiC OS?

Tags: networking, memory, qos

As per info from Juniper about memory buffers [here](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/traffic-mgmt-qfx/topics/concept/cos-qfx-series-buffer-configuration-understanding.html), a switch memory is divided into 2 main parts: Dedicated buffer and Shared buffer. The memory allocated  for a Dedicated buffer is equally distributed among all ports, and Shared buffer memory is available for shared consumption among ports based on specific traffic types. There is also a Shared headroom buffer that is used to keep traffic received during PFC Pause time window.

I want to understand how to get the following buffer limits in SONiC OS:

- Dedicated buffer size limit for a port
- Shared buffer size limit for a given port's queue
- Shared headroom size limit

Comment: Couldn't the architectures be different?  There are many ways to design a system.  For example, on high end cisco routers the interface buffer sizes are dynamic.